# How do I evaluate a radical function?

Tags: functional-equations

How do you solve this square root function? $f(x+9)=\sqrt{x+9}$.
I tried to solve it but I don't know what I should do after $\sqrt{x+18}$.

Comment: What do you mean by "solving [a] function"? What is the problem definition here?

Comment: And how did you get to $\sqrt{x+18}$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson probably $x\to x+9$.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $x = y-9$.

Then, $f((y-9)+9)=\sqrt{(y-9)+9}$, so $f(y)=\sqrt{y}$.